# Codeigniter unit testing with phpunit

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

Want to do unit testing of codeigniter project, searched for resources but most of them are outdated or incomplete. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Very good tutorial is given by codeiginiter [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/unit_testing.html) do check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to date solution https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test Just take a look and learn.